# Apply a function to rows inside multiple data.frames

Tags: r, lapply

Not sure how to ask this, but i'll give it a try:

I have 20 data.frames (e.g. 2006_1, 2006_2, 2007_1, 2007_2, ...) that I imported from MS Access.

Each data.frame has 10 columns and approximately 3 millions rows.

The first column in each data.frame is named `secuityName`, which is a list of stock tickers followed by some tags.

I would like to upcase every row in the `SecurityName` column in every one of the 20 data.frames.

The structure follows:

```
2006_1

> **SecurityName**   **...**
> AAPL abcdef        **...**
> MSFT abcdef        **...**

2006_2

> **SecurityName**   **...**
> AAPL abcdef        **...**
> MSFT abcdef        **...**
```

I would like each one to look like this:

```
2006_1

> **SecurityName**   **...**
> AAPL ABCDEF        **...**
> MSFT ABCDEF        **...**
```

I have a vector named *Raw_data_vector* that has all the data.frame names

Raw_data_vector

```
> 2006_1
> 2006_2
> 2007_1
> 2007_2
> ...
```

I have tried to use *lapply* but can't get it to work:

```
lapply(1:length(Raw_data_vector), function(x) toupper(get(x)[,1]),Raw_data_vector)
```

Comment: You can get the `data.frame` names using the pattern argument to `ls` however, variables that are named using numbers often cause more headaches than benefits.  you might want to think about changing their names before you continue.

Comment: @user1399173 Given the type and size of your data, you might find package [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) is more convenient and faster. Best to start with the user reviews and then the presentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.  I used `data.frames` that have characters that start their names so I don't wind up with any funny business.

```
oh6_1 <- data.frame(SecurityName=letters[1:20], v=1:20)
oh6_2 <- oh6_1

out <- lapply(ls(pattern = 'oh[0-9]_*'), 
              function(x) {
                df <- get(x)
                df[, 1] <- toupper(df[, 1])  
                return(df)
              })
```

Per the comments:

Depending on the names of your data.frames, you'll need to alter the `pattern` argument to `ls`.  Also, R doesn't change things in place (for the most part) instead it creates a new one.

You are seeing it as output to the console because it isn't assigned to anything!  Instead use something like `out <- llply(ls(...)...)`.  Then inspect  `out`.  It will be a list of the data frames you supplied with their additional column.  You can inspect `R` objects with `?str`.

Finally, this list of objects notion is a common result when working with many similar (or identical) things.  It is easy from here to continue doing whatever process you want, accept instead of calling `function(data.frame)` in something like a for loop, you can call `lapply(list of data frames, function)`

... Clear as mud to be sure.

If you must do the lowercase operation to the existing data.frame, you can use the always scary `assign` function:

```
myfun <- function(X) {
  df <- get(x)
  df[, 1] <- toupper(df[, 1])
  assign(x, df, .GlobalEnv)
  return(NULL)
}

lapply(ls(), myfun)
```

now look at your data.frames.

```
> oh6_1
   SecurityName  v
1             A  1
2             B  2
3             C  3
4             D  4
5             E  5
6             F  6
7             G  7
8             H  8
9             I  9
10            J 10
11            K 11
12            L 12
13            M 13
14            N 14
15            O 15
16            P 16
17            Q 17
18            R 18
19            S 19
20            T 20
>
```

Comment: Justin,  I just tried to implement your solution but the toupper() isn't staying.  It is outputting the correct results to the console but the original is not being overwritten (i.e., I'm looking in my workspace in RStudio and it is the same file when I view() it).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, it is only outputting the first data.frame to the console-- Not all three.  I'm more confused then ever now...